# Money abbreviations

Tags: reading-aloud, abbreviations

I can't find in Google any list of the money abbreviations used by English people.

I need to know how to continue this list:

- 1,000 = K
- 1,000,000 = M (or KK for odd speaking)

What is the next, maybe "B" of billion and also "KKK" for odd speaking?

What are the abbreviations for the other long known numbers?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milli-

Comment: @NS.X. We need to be careful with that when it comes to money. While K is indeed used for _thousands_ in money, and M is used for _millions_, I think B is used for billions (not G, as is used in computer memory). For example, see [this headline](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/state-controller-eyes-millionaires-close-15b-budget-gap-article-1.420301) and [this headline](http://online.wsj.com/article/BT-CO-20130415-714302.html). Likewise, it's [T for trillion](http://www.newsmax.com/InsideCover/clinton-debt-trillion-security/2010/05/27/id/360385).

Comment: Americans never use "KKK" to mean billion. The initialism "KKK" has a very controversial and negative connotation in American culture- google it.

Comment: @evan: I would suggest using Wikipedia or similar. Searching for KKK on Google, if someone is at work or school, might make HR come asking questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practice varies from publisher to publisher, but these are common abbreviations:

- **K** for thousands of dollars, Euros, etc. is a relatively recent
  adoption from computing and is not yet much used in formal contexts.
- The usual abbreviations for *million* and *billion* are **M** (or
  **m**) and **B** (or **b**); you may also encounter
  **Mn** (**mn**) and **Bn** (**bn**), particularly with
  commodities other than money. Be careful of your audience, however;
  the US employs the [**'short
  scale'**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales), in which
  each successive term represents one thousand times the previous term,
  and the UK has officially been on the short scale for a generation; but many other
  countries employ the 'long scale', in which each term after a million
  represents one *million* times the previous term.
- I have seen **T**, **Tr**, **tr**, **Tn** and **tn** for
  *trillion*. I advise the forms with **r** rather than **n**, since **tn** may be read as *tons* or *tonnes*.
- Money quantities of larger orders of magnitude are so rarely
  encountered that I have never seen an abbreviation for *quadrillion*.

Comment: Thankyou so much, but then you can tell me how would be the abbreviations for those quantities even if them exist or not?: quadrillion, quintillion, sextillion, septillion. how would abbreviate them you please?

Comment: @ElektroHacker I wouldn't abbreviate them with money, even if I had occasion to. With other matters I'd use decimal powers: 10^15, 10^18, 10^21, and so forth (or the superscripted versions, which won't display in a Comment).

Comment: sorry if I'm annoying but the thing is I'm programming an application which has a function that returns the abbreviated quantity, for example with "1.200.000" the function returns "1,2 M", so I need to know how would be a "quadrillion, quintillion, sextillion and a septillion" abbreviated (using letters) for this problem. so I prefer to know the opinion of a U.S. person, rather than invent me the abbreviated letters based on their names.

Comment: @ElektroHacker As far as I know, **standard abbreviations** for those do not exist. You'd have to go to ['scientific notation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Incidentally, in the English-speaking world we use the opposite convention for large decimal numbers: decimal fractions are marked with a `.` and successive thousand-multiples are marked with `,`, thus: `1,000,000.05`

Comment: Only just one more thing, exists a standard abbreviation for quantities less than a K of dollars?, for example for 999$?

Comment: @ElektroHacker Nope. Three digits is too short to abbreviate.

Comment: @ElektroHacker: For dollars, it's written $999, not 999$. For cents, it's 99¢.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I looked up _b_ in the dictionary, and found it was an abbreviation for _billion_. Same for _m_ for _million_. The dictionary I used didn't even list _trillion_ as an abbreviation for _t_, even though I've seen it used before. You could always denote 1.2 quadrillion as 1,200 T. Who gave you these program requirements?

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the correction. The function it's just an own idea to simplify some monetary conversions in a program but seems hard than I've imagine because don't exists the required abbreviations to complete it.

Comment: Maybe there aren't any standard abbreviations, but that seems like a silly thing to thwart the development of a program. Just use Qd, Qn, Sx, and Sp. In the context of computer output, does it really matter if those are "standard" abbreviations? I wouldn't think so.

Comment: FWIW, the only place I can actually remember seeing these abbreviations used is in *The Economist*, which is a British magazine. Most American publications, AFAIK, write out the quantity: "$1.2 million", "$3.4 trillion", etc. I think that many Americans would not understand immediately if you used abbreviations for these words without enough context for it to be obvious what they mean.

Comment: Here's a list of articles about the national debt, which is  good source for examples of American news sources discussing numbers in the range you are asking about: http://www.brillig.com/debt_clock/

Comment: It's also worth noting that, thanks to those pesky Romans and their numeral system, some people use "M" as a suffix to mean "thousand" (though this is now thankfully very rare) and "MM" to mean "Million" (still somewhat common).

Answer (score -3):

For this purpose, I think you can use the symbols used in metric prefixes as follows:

10*1   Deca    (D or da)   10      Ten /   Ten

10*2   Hecto   (h)     100     Hundred     /Hundred

10*3   Kilo    (k)     1,000   Thousand    /Thousand

10*6   Mega    (M)     1,000,000   Million     /Million

10*9   Giga    (G)     1,000,000,000   Billion     /Milliard

10*12      Tera    (T)     1,000,000,000,000   Trillion    /Billion

10*15      Peta    (P)     1,000,000,000,000,000   Quadrillion     /Billiard

10*18      Exa     (E)     1,000,000,000,000,000,000   Quintillion     Trillion

10*21      Zetta   (Z)  1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000  Sextillion/     Trilliard

10*24  Yotta   (Y) 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 Septillion/ Quadrillion

Comment: This is incorrect. Money is not referred to with metric prefixes.

Comment: Hi, I believe that simply saying a solution is incorrect does not solve the problem. In this case, it seems that there is no absolutely correct answer. It is like choosing between bad and worse! If a programmer uses the above solution, does it cause any harm to the program or to the English language? if not, it seems logical to me to use a similar (or close) answer for a specific purpose. (I hope I could have explained what I mean through my poor English)

Comment: Sorry, perhaps *incorrect* was an unclear way to put it. There **is** a standard way of abbreviating large quantities of money, as detailed in StoneyB's answer, and the metric abbreviations are not the standard. Even in a programming context it's important to hold to known standards so that those who work on the code in the future can understand it easily.

Comment: I also prefer using a standard way but as StoneyB explained, "standard abbreviations for those do not exist". Then, J.R. proposed using "Qd,& etc. for this case and asked that: "In the context of computer output, does it really matter if those are "standard" abbreviations?" Then I asked myself why one should improvise a set of abbreviations if there already exists a very close set of abbreviations which we may use for this purpose? In an academic or expert context, which one is easier to understand: "one Peta or P dollars" or "one Qd. dollars"? (note that Qd. is not standard but P somehow is)

Comment: Yes, I would say using P, E, Z, Y would be OK for > 10^15, since there are no standard abbreviations. However, there *are* standard abbreviations for 10^3-10^12. That's the main part of your answer I disagreed with.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, among the abbreviations you disagreed, "K" is used nowadays in social networks to show the quantity of persons' fans; for instance we see somebody has "25K" audience or fans in instagram which of course does not mean "Kilo" but "thousand". So, this one may also be used in this context.